# Javascript to validate URL

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a text box where the user will enter a URL, and I need to validate this URL.

For example: I'm only trying to validate this part:

```
(https/http/ftp://www.gmail.two letters here)
```

I mentioned two letters there because many TLDs exist such as .cc, .me, etc.

I tried this regex which did not work:

```
(/((http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)|)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you give us what you have right now?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the captures? what didn't work? what was your example of failure?

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst:I've already added that in my question.

Comment: By what you have, I mean the actual Javascript that regex matches the text. You may be approaching it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could just simply use:

```
((https?|ftp):\/\/)+([\w\d\.]+([\w]{2,6})?)
```

Depending on what your need is, you can go with simplicity or with... overkill. :p

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>http://www.stackoverflow.com</li>
                <li>httpwww.stackoverflow.com</li>
                <li>a.b.c</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsURL(str_url){  

        var strRegex = "[a-zA-z]+://[^\s]*";  
              var re=new RegExp(strRegex);  
              if (re.test(str_url)){  
                  return (true);  
              }else{  
                  return (false);  
              }  
          }  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("li").click(function(){  
            var url=$(this).text();  
                alert(url+" /n IsURL:"+IsURL(url));  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: :Try a word like google,it will say it is valid.It should have (http://www.)Even it say this is valid(httpwww.test.co).What is the regex for checking empty vaidation

Comment: @user1263374 The last version was supported the second-level domain , so existing the bug which you figure out. This is the simplest version can suit for almost all basic patterns.